# Accessing the button id of fragment A from fragment B

Tags: android, xml

I have created Fragment A and Fragment B , which has separate buttons on each fragment , I need to enable the button on fragment B until and unless button on fragment A is clicked , how can I do this as I am new to this android .

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways :

1. create public static variable and access it from other fragment
2. use custom [BroadcastReceiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) and call it when button of fragment1 is called, and receive that in fragment2.
3. use [EventBus](http://androidgig.com/eventbus-library-in-android/), call the event and receive it in another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

when you have to click on fragment A button then enable the button on fragment B in on attach or on create method here you need to use interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define an Interface in fragment A
2. Implement the Interface in fragment B
3. onClick of Button in Fragment A Call interface, and message is delivered to fragment B.